# How to run php on non-standard port in nginx?

Tags: php, nginx

I have working nginx on standard port 80 for node app on ubuntu server.  /etc/nginx/sites-available/default is:

```
server {

    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;
    location / {

        proxy_pass http://localhost:3333;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
     }
}
```

I have installed php7. I want to serve php files on port 8585 using nginx. So that example.com:8585/info.php  points to /var/www/html/info.php on file system.

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can write an additional server block

```
server {
    listen 8585;
    listen somename:8585;
    server_name somename alias another.alias;
    root html;
    index index.html index.htm;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```